AWS SAM CLI and terraform variables
I am using AWS SAM CLI with the terraform hook.  I have TFVAR files for each of my deployment environments.  Is there some way for it read those files?
In some cases, I can read them from environment variables, if I prefix those variable names TF_VAR_.  But this is not consistenly available.
When you call:
$ sam local invoke
It appears to execute a "terraform plan" under the covers.  If I set my terraform variables as environment variables prefixed with TF_VAR_, this command works OK.
However, when I try this:
$ sam build
It does not see my variables, and it prompts me to enter them.
Ideally, for both commands, I would like to pass in a parameter like terraform's -var-file.  But I don't see a way to do this from the docs.
